# Gwt Image Upload and mysql blob storage

Tags: mysql, gwt, gwt-rpc, gwtupload

I have been googling for some time but I still havent found what Im looking for.

What I want to do is set a submit form in my GWT app and receive an image. Send this image to the server side to store in my mysql database as a blob, so that I can reach for it and display it later on. Ive been trying with GWTUpload and it seemed really good but I couldnt change the code to make it work with mysql.

Im a real begginer with GWT and I know that this is a big question but some pointers in the right way would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the image in a folder of your server and save the link to the file in your MYSQL database. This would also make replacing images easier. Also it's simpler to handle a file instead of a blob.